# String.split(".") is not splitting my long String

Tags: java

I'm doing the following:

```
String test = "this is a. example";
String[] test2 = test.split(".");
```

the problem: `test2` has no items. But there are many `.` in the `test` `String`.

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Note that [public String[] split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a **regex**.

You need to escape the [special char](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) `.`.

Use `String[] test2 = test.split("\\.");`

Now you're telling Java:

"*Don't take `.` as the special char `.`, take it as the regular char `.`*".

Note that escaping a regex is done by `\`, but in Java, `\` is written as `\\`.

---

As suggested in the comments by @OldCurmudgeon (+1), you can use [public static String quote(String s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) that "*Returns a literal pattern String for the specified String*":

`String[] test2 = test.split(Pattern.quote("."));`

Comment: If that answers your question you should probably mark it as answer ;-)

Comment: Suggest using `Pattern.quote(".")` instead of hacking the string with escapes.

Answer (score 10):

The dot `.` is special regex character. It means match any. You need to escape the character, which in Java is done with `\\`.

Once it is escaped, it won't be treated as special and will be matched just like any other character.

So `String[] test2 = test.split("\\.");` should do the trick nicely!